# How to determine how much storage space a column takes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to determine how much storage space on the disk a column takes in a table in Oracle?

I'm running Oracle 11gR2 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`VSIZE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions248.htm#SQLRF06162) to get the number of bytes for the internal representation of a value.

If you want the total space used by a column, you'll need to sum over all the rows (unless the type used has a fixed length).

The [`DUMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions062.htm#SQLRF00635) function will also give you the size and raw representation of a value, but not in a format amenable to easy summation.

Comment: Thanks. Does Oracle never tries to compress table data, e.g. if it realizes all values for a given column is the same?

Comment: Not if you don't tell it to. There are various options for that depending on your scenario and your budget. Index compression works like you describe though.

Comment: The link for VSIZE is wrong or outdated - it points to VARIANCE.  Here is the correct link:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions249.htm#SQLRF06162